# 413 Request Entity Too Large For HttpClient

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httpclient, http-status-code-413

Once i send the HttpClient request through the PostAsJsonAsync i get the response as Request Entity too large. but i can directly call to webapi and send the request and returns a successfull response. but through the PostAsJsonAsync it returns the 413 error code.

This is my code

```
    var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("API_HOST")) };
    const string api = "CmSaveChange" + "/" + "SaveChange";
    var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(api, entity).Result;
    var retunValue = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<HybridDictionary>().Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to be solved on the **server**-side (self hosting HttpSelfHostServer or IIS).
The buffers have to be set to a higher value.
**If the host run's under IIS:**
[Configure IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710925/requestentitytoolarge-response-from-web-api-when-trying-to-upload-a-file-with-ht)

**If the server is running as HttpSelfHostServer:**
You have to set higher values (as needed) to the config parameters.
**Example for vb.net**

```
Dim cSelhostConfiguration As String = cIPADressePort
' Note: cIPADressePort contains the IP address and port on which the host is listen
Dim config As New HttpSelfHostConfiguration(cSelhostConfiguration)
'Set here the needed size (in bytes)
config.MaxBufferSize = 250000000
config.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 250000000
'
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name:="DefaultApi",
routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}",
defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
)
'
Using server As New HttpSelfHostServer(config)
Try
server.OpenAsync().Wait()
Console.WriteLine("")
Console.WriteLine("WebService started... ")
Console.WriteLine("Waiting for work...")
  Catch aggEx As AggregateException
Console.WriteLine("Error loading Server")
  End Try
  Console.WriteLine()
Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close the server")
  Console.ReadLine()
End Using
```