# Bot with Skype Channel RequestEntityTooLarge

Tags: botframework, skype

I am returning a hero card from my botframework bot hosted on IIS. Works perfect when testing with my IISExpress and Emulator. However, when I deploy to our data center IIS server and try to use Skype Channel then I always get the following error:

Operation returned an invalid status code 'RequestEntityTooLarge'

I have already increased maxRequestLength="20971510" in our web.config, but even then it should not matter. The hero card is pretty small size, and the image is small as well.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**. So Skype does not support adaptive cards, but web chat does. On web chat I observe that some images come through fine, and for others I get BadRequest error. I also observed that images that fail are typically higher resolution.

Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'

Comment: Did you have a look to this SO reply? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710925/requestentitytoolarge-response-from-web-api-when-trying-to-upload-a-file-with-ht

Comment: I have, doesn't help.

Comment: Which SDK of the botframework are you using, .NET or NodeJS?  Do you have an example of the code that is sending the payload to the Skype Channel that is getting the RequestEntityTooLarge error?